# Run Octave function from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, function, octave

I'm trying to write a function in Octave directly in VB.NET using the Octave.NET package.

```vb
Public Sub TEST()
        OctaveContext.OctaveSettings.OctaveCliPath = "C:\User\AppData\Local\Programs\GNU Octave\Octave-7.3.0\mingw64\bin\octave-cli.exe"

        Using octave As New OctaveContext()
            With octave

                'input
                .Execute("
                         A=147;
                         B=26.3;
                         C=5.4;
                         d=0.35*A;
                         ")

                'calc
                .Execute("
                         function S=function_test(A,B,C,d)
                                                
                         S=-1*A*B*C*d;

                         end
                         ")

                'Label8.Text = .Execute("d")
                Label8.Text = .Execute("S=function_test(A,B,C,d)")
            End With
        End Using

End Sub
```

Through the shell the function is executed normally but if I execute it from VB, this error appears at the label8 row:

> Octave.NET.Core.Exceptions.OctaveScriptError: 'error: 'function_test' undefined near line 1, column 3

and if I try this:

```
.Execute("
A=1;
B=2;
C=5;
d=1*A;

function S=test(A,B,C,d)
    S=A*B*C*d;
end

S=test(A,B,C,d)
")
```

the error is:

> Octave.NET.Core.Exceptions.OctaveScriptError: 'error: test: function called with too many inputs
> error: called from
> test

Comment: According to [Functions and Script Files](https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/octave_7.html) it seems to me that the end of a function is declared with `endfunction`, not `end`. Does that help?

Comment: For Matlab compatibility Octave works with either specific or general block terminations, so end should work just fine

Comment: yes, I tried and the error remains